# DAG reduce edges by transitivity

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

I have a DAG like this

$G_1 = \lbrace A \to B \to C \rbrace$

My algorithm modify $G_1$ so it will be like this

$ G_2 = \lbrace A \to C, B \to C \rbrace $

I now that $G_2$ is not a transitive reduction of $G_1$. How it is called this operation?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: basically, $G_2$ contains the edge $(a, b)$ of $G_1$ if and only if $b$ is a sink node and exist a path between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You need to define the operation more formally. For example, what happens if I apply it on $A\to B\to C\to D?$. Do you wish to create a graph with no paths on 3 vertices?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, look at my edit. I hope is more clear now. In your examples, the result graph will be $\lbrace A \to D, B \to D, C \to D \rbrace$.

Comment: So, basically, $G_2$ is a set of sinks and a set of vertices that points to them, without any 3-path in the graph. I don't think this has a standard name, but I think the question is better suited for [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/).